# How to transfer text from RTF to Word Document in c#

Tags: ms-word

hI I need to transfer text from richTextbox to word document and also in plain text on button_click. I need assistance on this please.

I got a vb code but need in csharp.

```
Dim wrdApp As Word.Application

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Set wrdApp = New Word.Application
End Sub

Private Sub Command2_Click()
    Clipboard.SetText RichTextBox1.TextRTF, vbCFRTF
    With wrdApp
        .Documents.Add
        .Selection.Paste
        .ActiveDocument.SaveAs App.Path & "RTFDOC2.doc", _
                wdFormatDocument
        .Visible = True
        .Activate
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I found and put the following together based off [this site](http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2007/11/03/creating-word-document-using-c/):

```
object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
object Visible = true;
object start1 = 0;
object end1 = 0;
Word.Document adoc = WordApp.Documents.Add(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
Word.Range rng = adoc.Range(ref start1, ref missing);

try
{              
    Clipboard.SetText(richTextBox.Text, TextDataFormat.Rtf);
    WordApp.Selection.Paste();
    string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    object filename = path + @"\MyWord.doc";

    adoc.SaveAs(ref filename, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

    WordApp.Visible = true;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call this VBA code using the activeX-IF of msword.